# REST SDK, How can I get the right result from this wsdl?

Tags: c++, rest, sdk, wsdl

the wsdl file is in this page:

```
http://202.102.95.130:9999/epeisong-ws/AccountService?wsdl
```

I want to call the "login" function, the corresponding wsdl is:

```
-<xs:complexType name="login">    
-<xs:sequence><xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>    
<xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>    
<xs:element name="logSourceType" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>    
</xs:complexType>-<xs:complexType name="loginResponse">    
-<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="returnwalletID" type="xs:int"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
```

here is the c++ code:

```css
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wcout << L"Calling HTTPGetAsync..." << std::endl;
    HTTPGetAsync().wait();
}`

  `pplx::task<void> HTTPGetAsync()
{
    http_client client(U("http://202.102.95.130:9999/epeisong-ws/AccountService?wsdl/"));
    utility::string_t functionname = U("login");
    utility::string_t userName = U("test1");
    utility::string_t password = U("1234567");
    utility::string_t logSourceType = U("1");`  

    utility::string_t accounturl = functionname + U("/") + userName + U("/") + password + U("/") + logSourceType + U("/");
    uri_builder builder(accounturl);

    return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string()).then([](http_response response)
    {
        std::wostringstream stream;
        stream << L"Server returned status code " << response.status_code() << L'.' << std::endl;
        std::wcout << stream.str();

        stream.str(std::wstring());
        stream << L"Content type: " << response.headers().content_type() << std::endl;
        stream << L"Content length: " << response.headers().content_length() << L"bytes" << std::endl;
        std::wcout << stream.str();
        auto bodyStream = response.body();
        streams::stringstreambuf sbuffer;
        auto& target = sbuffer.collection();

        bodyStream.read_to_end(sbuffer).get();
        stream.str(std::wstring());
        stream << L"Response body: " << target.c_str();
        std::wcout << stream.str();
        getchar();
    });
}
```

but it just returned the total wsdl code in

```
http://202.102.95.130:9999/epeisong-ws/AccountService?wsdl
```

I want to get the the "login" fun's return value, what should I do?

Comment: Please remove the "REST" tag - this has nothing to do with REST.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely familiar with the syntax for the request, but your base URL includes the ?wsdl suffix which is likely interpreted on the server side as a request for the wsdl document itself.  Try removing that part of the URL from the initial http_client instantiation and see if you get further.